# How to change the icon and exe file name when exporting Eclipse RCP in another RCP product(Papyrus.exe)

Tags: icons, eclipse-rcp, papyrus

I develop an Eclipse RCP product in Papyrus.exe ([Papyrus](https://eclipse.dev/papyrus/)). My product file has the branding and launching all set up. But when I export the product, the exe file name is still Papyrus.exe, not Eclipse.exe nor my own configuration in "Launcher name". And the icon of the exe file is still Papyrus icon, not the bmp files I specified.
The funny thing is that, the .ini file is of the right name, and when I launch the exe file, the icons on the window and workbench is correct. Plus, I don't have a "eclipsec.exe" or in my case maybe it should be "papyrusc.exe".

[my product configuration file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvZB4.png)

[the export folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irsX0.png)

[the other file icons are right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVKgf.png)

I tried change the app name and launcher name, but it didn't take effect at all.

I wonder if it is because I don't have the "exlipsec.exe" exported, or my export is not successful. Does this have anything to do with the RCP I developed my RCP in? I want to change the icon and name of the exe file. The rest of the exported files are correct. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: The old Export RCP wizard is deprecated, the only supported export method is using [tag:tycho], [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html), see if that works. The RCP export doesn't normally generate the `xxxc` executable, that is not the problem.